# Remove a different list of AD groups from a long list of users

Tags: powershell, csv, import-csv

I am trying to create a CSV for AD cleanup work that will contain a couple hundred users' `SamAccountName` and a list of groups to remove the user from. Each user will have a different list of groups to remove them from.

CSV will look like this:

```
SamAccountName,ADgroupName1,ADgroupName2,ADgroupName3,ADgroupName4,etc...
user1,Group1,Group2,Group3,Group4
user2,Group2,Group3,,,
user3,Group5,,,,
```

The script I have so far:

```
# Get the list of SAMAccountNames
$user = Import-Csv .\GroupsToRemove.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SAMAccountName

foreach ($user in $users) {
    # Loop through the user list and select the list of groups to remove for each user
    # from the CSV and set to the $Groups array
    $Group = @()
    $Group = %{(Import-Csv .\GroupsToRemove.csv | Where-Object {$_.SamAccountName -eq $user})} | select "GroupName*"

    foreach ($group in $Groups) {
        # Remove the AD groups from each User
        Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user -Member $Group -Confirm:$false
    }
}
```

I think part of the problem is that when I'm importing the group names from the CSV it also adds the column names into the `$Group` array? So the `Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` command is failing?

`$groups` output is like below:

```
GroupName1 : Group1
GroupName2 : Group2
GroupName3 : Group3
GroupName4 : Group4
```

Comment: You are doing `$user =` and then iterating through `$users`. Change `$user = ` to `$users = `. You're also doing the same mistake with `$Group =`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't define the AD groups as separate columns in the CSV. Make the groups one column with a comma (or other delimiter) separated string:

```
SamAccountName,Groups
user1,"Group1,Group2,Group3,Group4"
user2,"Group2,Group3"
user3,"Group5"
```

That way you can handle the groups from the CSV like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\GroupsToRemove.csv

foreach ($user in $csv) {
    $groups = $user.Groups -split ',' |
              Get-ADGroup |
              Select-Object -Expand DistinguishedName
    Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user.SamAccountName -Member $groups -Confirm:$false
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Never occurred to me to have all the groups in the one column that worked great!